# Why does gcc 11.3.0 append "a-" to dependency file name?

Tags: gcc, makefile, dependencies, c-preprocessor

Under gcc 11.3.0, when entering the command, gcc -M -MD sourcefile.c, a file named "a-sourcefile.d" is created.  However, under gcc 9.4.0, the "a-" prefix is not present.

Is this correct behavour?

I was expecting .d files without the "a-" prefix.

EDIT:  I noticed the issue when using a makefile but I am able to reproduce the issue without a makefile, using commands entered manually.

More detailed information:

I have 2 different machines:
Machine 1:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
```

Machine 2:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
```

Assume each machine has identical directories containing 3 files: main.c, library.c and library.h.

Contents of main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  LibFunc1();
  return 0;
}
```

library.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"

void LibFunc1(void)
{
  puts("Library Function 1");
}
```

library.h:

```
void LibFunc1(void);
```

commands run on both machines:

```
gcc -M -MD library.c
gcc -M -MD main.c
```

Contents of directory on Machine 1:

```
$ ls
library.c  library.d  library.h  main.c  main.d
```

Contents of directory on Machine 2:

```
$ ls
a-library.d  a-main.d  library.c  library.h  main.c
```

So, why the discrepancy?  No makefile, no special variables being used (as far as I am aware unless there's some environment variable that is persistent).

Machine 2 is a fresh install and was booted up just before the commands were entered.

Comment: Is `gcc -M -MD sourcefile.c` the full command with which you observed this effect?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: To get the same file name in 11.3.0 without the 'a-' prefix, I have to enter this command: `gcc -E -MD main.c > /dev/null`

Comment: Another interesting observation: on my 20.04 machine, I installed gcc-11 (first had to add new ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test and I ended up with 11.1.0) and when I enter the command `gcc -M -MD main.c` I end up with the 'a-' prefix!  That is on the same machine.

Comment: That all seems very surprising, @AWM.  You might want to consider asking the GCC maintainers for comment.  Moreover, do note that part of the point of using `-MD` is to *avoid* the effect of `-E`, so adding the latter is counterproductive.  If generating the dependency information without actually compiling is sufficient for you then it is probably the `-MD` you should be dropping. In that case, `-M -MF library.d` may be what you're after.

Comment: Or maybe try just dropping the `-M` without adding `-E`, as `-MD` implies `-M`.

Comment: I installed gcc-11 on a centos 7 VM and it has the same behavour as it did on Ubuntu.

Comment: Dropping -M without the -E results in this error: `$ gcc -MD main.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccN17GRw.o: in function 'main':
main.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to 'LibFunc1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: You should be starting with a compilation command that works without any of the `-M*` options, especially if you're using `-MD`. Evidently, you are not doing that.  Either add `-c`, or use `-M -MF library.d` instead of `-MD`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there actually is a bug about this issue in the gcc bug tracker: [Bug 109183 - [regression?] since GCC 11.1, -MM -MMD generates "a-" prefixed dependency files](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109183)

Thanks @John Bollinger for responding.

Answer (score 0):

> Under gcc 11.3.0, when entering the command, gcc -M -MD sourcefile.c, a file named "a-sourcefile.d" is created. However, under gcc 9.4.0, the "a-" prefix is not present.

There is no documented difference in the behavior of the `-M` or `-MD` option in [GCC 11](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.3.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) relative to [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.5.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).  These have been stable for a fairly long time, so I think this ...

> I was expecting .d files without the "a-" prefix.

... is a reasonable expectation.  In fact, I think it's *so* reasonable, especially in light of the documentation, that I'm inclined to guess that the issue is not as described in the question.  Perhaps one or more additional command-line options were specified, or perhaps the source file name was not as claimed.  This sort of thing might creep in under the radar if, for example, the build command were constructed with the help of `make` variables.

Comment: @AWM, look at `make`'s output to see the actual commands it is executing.  I bet you will find that they are different on the two machines, and that that difference explains the behavior you observe.  In that case, *why* they are different would probably have to do with the makefile, the environment, and possibly other factors; this would be the subject of a different question.